# Efficiently compute element-by-element minima of two matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have two matrices A and B with typical elements a_{i,j} and b_{i,j}. I want to obtain matrix C with a typical element c_{i,j} = min{ a_{i,j}, b_{i,j} }.

How do I do that efficiently in R?

Comment: Henrik, thanks. I did not find the other one as it was not tagged with [tag:matrix].

Comment: Should I delete the question? I tried to do so, but I got a warning that my account could be blocked if I did this more than once (e.g. something similar happening in the future).

Comment: No need to delete. Just leave it up. Since it is duped, It can now serve as reference point

Comment: Cool... A downvote despite my explanation in the comments?

Comment: @Sotos, thanks. I am used to MathJax formatting as in Cross Validated, but I could not get it to work here (dollar signs did not do the trick). How do I get it to work? I did not show a brute force attempt as I was asking for an efficient implementation. To that end I did not have anything to offer, unfortunately.

Comment: That's how users  in here operate. It has goods and bads. The only certainty is that it's not personal

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `pmin` function, it does exactly that.

```
set.seed(123)

A <- matrix(runif(9),nrow=3)
#          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#[1,] 0.2875775 0.8830174 0.5281055
#[2,] 0.7883051 0.9404673 0.8924190
#[3,] 0.4089769 0.0455565 0.5514350
A
B <- matrix(runif(9),nrow=3)
B
#          [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
#[1,] 0.4566147 0.6775706 0.89982497
#[2,] 0.9568333 0.5726334 0.24608773
#[3,] 0.4533342 0.1029247 0.04205953

pmin(A,B)
#          [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
#[1,] 0.2875775 0.6775706 0.52810549
#[2,] 0.7883051 0.5726334 0.24608773
#[3,] 0.4089769 0.0455565 0.04205953
```

Alexis